# Perform actions on server after CircleCI deployment

Tags: django, ssh, deployment, circleci

I have a Django project that I deploy on a server using CircleCI. The server is a basic cloud server, and I can SSH into it.

I set up the `deployment` section of my `circle.yml` file, and everything is working fine. I would like to automatically perform some actions on the server after the deployment (such as migrating the database or reloading gunicorn).

I there a way to do that with CircleCI? I looked in the docs but couldn't find anything related to this particular problem. I also tried to put `ssh user@my_server_ip` after my deployment step, but then I get stuck and cannot perform any action. I can successfully SSH in, but the rest of the commands is not called.

Here is what my ideal `circle.yml` file would look like:

```
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: develop
      commands:
        - rsync --update ./requirements.txt user@server:/home/user/requirements.txt
        - rsync -r --update ./myapp/ user@server:/home/user/myapp/
        - ssh user@server
        - workon myapp_venv
        - cd /home/user/
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting a `post_deploy.sh` file on the server, and putting this line on the `circle.yml`:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_myhost user@server 'post_deploy.sh'`
It executes the instructions in the `post_deploy.sh` file, which is exactly what I wanted.